# VSCode (Mac M1, v12.5.1) - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'command')

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core

yesterday I saw vscode cannot load the test project and throw me this error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuxF9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC5yD.png)

*Context, I'm working with MacOS, v12.5.1, Chip Apple M1 Pro, VSCode July 2022 (version 1.70.2), dotnet v.3.1.419*

Answer (score 0):

Solution may be this one:

https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer/issues/370

The suggested workaround is to go to settings - .NET Core Test Explorer - Tree Mode and set it to flat.

Then the tests work. Fix looks like coming soon.